# android how to accsess base module drawables in feture module xml files

Tags: android, android-resources, android-module

i have base module which is library module and the feature module which is my application how can i set the  src of the imageView which is in the some layout of the module feature to the drawable file which i have in base module  ?

i have tried this code but it gives me resource not found in the build time :

```
 <ImageView
                    android:src="@com.example.app.base:drawable/image"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 1):

One cannot access resources of base_module into library_module.  But other way it works fine i.e When you add your library_module  dependency into a base_module you can access resources of library_module into base_module.